# rich:calendar shorten size of time input fields

Tags: richfaces, jboss6.x

In the image attached, you'll see the digit input fields to set the time. By stretching out the entire calendar, I was able to show the spinners a bit more.  I'm trying to figure out how to decrease the width of the digit input fields. If there is a way to increase size of the spinner arrows then that would be helpful too. Thank you.

Manual I was reading: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs.html#sect-Component_Reference-richcalendar-Client-side_customization

My code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .rf-cal-sp-btn{
    width : 15px;
    }
    .rf-cal-sp-up{
    width : 20px;
    }
    .rf-cal-sp-down{
    width : 20px;
    }
</style>


<h:panelGroup>          
                <rich:calendar value="#{bean.timeField}" id="id1"  
                        popup="true"  datePattern="M/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"
                        enableManualInput="false" required="true"
                        showApplyButton="true" popupStyle="width:350px;" popupClass="rf-cal-sp-btn rf-cal-sp-up rf-cal-sp-down"
                        requiredMessage="blah blah required">
                        <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this"  bypassUpdates="#{true}"  render="id1 id1Msg"/>
                </rich:calendar>
                <rich:message for="id1" id="id1Msg" />
            </h:panelGroup>
```

What my calendar looks like: "http://snag.gy/LvzvA.jpg"

Comment: While inspecting the element in firefox, I discovered the following style is being used: 
    table .component input {width: 95%;}

This is causing the undesireable effect.  However when attempting to change this in forge-styles.css the style in still being used (like I never commented it out).  How can I get the app to use the forge-styles.css I'm editing instead of using a generated one?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the external CSS file but I was able to get past this with an Internal Style Sheet.
I've added this bit of code after the ui:composition and before the form tag.

```
<h:head>    
    <style type="text/css">
    #content table .component input {
        width: 70%; 
    }
    </style>
</h:head>
```

Comment: You can get more specific with the component:
    
    <h:head> 
 <style type="text/css">
 #content table .rf-cal-sp-inp-ctnr input {
   width: 70%; 
  }  
 </style>
    </h:head>